# Python list iteration not working with conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am a beginner in the python world and I really like this language so far!

In my exercices session I've found the following one: "Use a loop to display elements from a given list present at odd index positions" and I've come to 2 solutions.

However I cannot see why the following 2 snippets of code are not prompting the same result.

1st one:

```
#THIS ONE IS WORKING
my_list = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

for index in range(len(my_list)):
    #print(type(index), end=" ")
    if index % 2 != 0:
        print(my_list[index], end=" ")
```

2nd one:

```
#THIS ONE IS **NOT** WORKING
my_list = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

for item in my_list:
    #print(type(item), end=" ")
    if item % 2 != 0:
        print(item, end=" ")
```

As you can see I've thought that maybe the elements are not an **integer** for the 2nd snippet and that's why I've tried to print the type.

So the result should be for both snippets:

```
20 40 60 80 100
```

And for the 2nd one I receive no output.

Can you help me in understanding why? And sorry beforehand if it's something very trivial for you that I did not see. Not even ChatGPT could've help me here...

Comment: The first block iterates over the index, the second over the items, which gives different values to the `%` operator.

Comment: First one is iterating over 0, 1, 2, 3 etc... Second one is iterating over 10, 20, 30... where all items are divisible by 2

Comment: In the second example you are iterating over the elements of the list, so the `item % 2 != 0` always evaluates to False, since all elements are even numbers. If you want to access the index use `for i, item in enumerate(my_list)` where `i` is index and `item` is element.

Comment: When you iterate over list, you iterate over elements, not indexes, just print `item` to see what you work with. All elements in the list are even. That said, don't use anti-pattern `range(len(some_list))`, use `enumerate(some_list)` instead.

Comment: Useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using enumerate, you can loop through both the index and the item, and then check if the index is odd to display elements at odd index positions.

```
my_list = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

for index, item in enumerate(my_list):
    if index % 2 != 0:
        print(item, end=" ")
```

Comment: The straightforward and best answer. IMO this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Indeed this is the nicest way to solve it. My thinking is more C/C++ oriented as I come from that environment.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is the extra trailing space

Answer (score 1):

You should use *enumerate()* as this gives you both index and value at each iteration.

Using that, you can then unpack a generator and print in a single step (also without unnecessary trailing space as some other answers will create) like this:

```
my_list = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

print(*(v for i, v in enumerate(my_list) if i & 1))
```

**Output:**

```
20 40 60 80 100
```

**Note:**

You can achieve the correct output without testing odd/even for any given index by using a slice as follows:

```
print(*my_list[1::2])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second code, you are iterating the elements, not the indexes of them.You cannot make a calculation of its indexes in that way. Maybe you can use a enumeration but the first code is much more useful in your situation

Comment: *"Maybe you can use a enumeration but the first code is much more useful in your situation"* The opposite. `enumerate` is much more pythonic than using a loop over `range` to index into a list. We don't want to encourage beginners to get into the habit of using the non-pythonic version.